How to do null safe calls (?. operator) with Arrays?
I am trying to get items from a nullable array using a safe call (?. operator).
data class myObject(val i: Int)

var arr: Array<myObject>? = arrayOf(myObject(123),myObject(456))
// var arr: Array<myObject>? = arrayOf(myObject(123),null)

println(arr?[1] ?: myObject(1)) // Doesn't work
println(arr?.[1] ?: myObject(1))// Doesn't work
println(arr[1]? ?: myObject(1)) // Doesn't work
//Intended output: myObject(i=456) or myObject(i=1)

I can say that !! operator works as intended (println(arr!![1]) prints myObject(i=456))
But how do I get the safe call operator (?.) to work with arrays?

array?.get(1)

I found the same solution. [index] brackets are just a shorthand for get and set operators. (Here is some info on operator overriding for when writing your own classes)

(Answering my own question)
println(arr?.get(1) ?: myObject(1))
[index] brackets are just a shorthand for get and set methods. (Here is some info on operator overriding. Every operator (eg. a+=b and a++) has a corresponding function (a.plusAssign(b) and a.inc()) if you need to use ?. with one of them, check the long-from function.
As another user pointed out, this question is a duplicate of ?. operator on a nullable array
